# 3D Render With JS

Tags: javascript, colors, 3d

I have a 3D Render of moving cubes, they are different colors, so it's like a rainbow. But I want to know if there is a way to make the squares pulse colors.
https://repl.it/@AlexanderLuna/R-A-I-N-B-O-W#index.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okey.. apparently I'm procrastinating and spent the last hour playing around with your Repl..

This might not be exactly what you're after, but maybe it'll help some..

```
  class Cube {
    constructor(x_, y_, z_, size_, offset_) {
    this.x = x_;
    this.y = y_;
    this.z = z_;
    this.size = size_;
    this.offset = offset_;
    this.angle = 0;
    
    this.tick = 1;   // starting point
    this.hueSpeed = 2;   // tick modifier
  }

  
  update(f) {
    this.y = map(f(this.angle + this.offset), -1, 1, this.size / 2, height - this.size / 2);
    this.angle += 0.05;
    colorMode(HSB, this.tick, 1, 1);

    /** 
    * The request is there to simply regulate the frequency of the tick a bit.. 
    * Though we do need to cancel the previous request if hadn't yet fired
    * Which I'm apparently to lazy to do atm
    */
    window.requestAnimationFrame((e)=>{
      this.tick += this.hueSpeed;
      (this.tick > 150 || this.tick < 2) && (this.hueSpeed *= -1);
    });
  }

  render() {
    push();
    stroke(0);
    translate(this.x, this.y, this.z);
    box(this.size);
    pop();
  }
}
```

This is the cube.js script file, the only one altered.

Answer (score 2):

`colorMode(HSB, nums.x * nums.y, 1, 1)` Is your answere.
Apply it in the update function and play around with the colors by altering 'nums.x * nums.y' values.

Use a timer or a simple tick (you can simply do `tick++` in the update function) as a modifier until it reaches a certain iteration and then reset (or jump the value). You should get the desired effect.